# UINavigationBar detail text label

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

Is there a way to add a detailed text label and an image in the text bar like this one? I have not been able to find anything that can show me how to do this so I am not sure if there is an easy way to accomplish this. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Create custom UIView and add it as a titleView to your navigation bar like this:

```
let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,30))

let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,15))
label1.text = "Julie"
let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,15,200,15))
label2.text = "@therealjulie"

titleView.addSubview(label1)
titleView.addSubview(label2)

navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

You can add the image the same way.